# Include git information on parceljs build

Tags: npm, parceljs

I have a `TypeScript/React` web app that uses `ParcelJS` and I would like to have either a step in the build or a simple way of using a resource file that holds git information.

Not sure if there is something that can generate the `git` information during the build, I'm using `npm` to launch parcel.

If parcel can load a resource file and make it accessible that could also work by having properties.

My end goal would be to display version and git commit point in the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using parcel2 (I'm not sure this would be possible in parcel1).

Parcel2 uses babel to transpile typescript by default (through the `@parcel/transformer-babel` plugin). The babel configuration for this plugin can be over-ridden by simply including a `.babelrc` (for configuration relevant to only a subset of the project) or `babel.config.json` file (for configuration that will apply to the entire project). See [this scenario matrix](https://astegmaier.github.io/parcel2-monorepo-babel-bug/parcel-goals) that I made in the process of fixing [this bug](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/4120) for details about exactly what babel config files should be picked up by parcel. (The "proposed fixes" are merged into parcel2 as of the latest nightly release).

With the ability to supply your own babel configuration, you should be able to use [this babel plugin](https://github.com/renke/babel-plugin-git-version) to inject git repository information into your code.

(Since you're using typescript, you'll also need to make sure to include [@babel/preset-typescript](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) or [@babel/plugin-transform-typescript](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-typescript) in your babel config as well).